# Are there any strategies to minimise the impact of copy and paste block on the UX?

Tags: website-design, copy-paste

Follow on from [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110855/how-big-of-a-deal-is-blocking-copy-pasting-on-a-website)

As part of a website the client has asked for a copy and paste block to be implemented.
While it has been generally agreed in the other question that this is problematic, at the end of the day the client is king and can have what they like.

If they are firm in wanting a copy and paste block applied, are there any strategies or mechanisms I can put in place to minimise the impact upon the UX? Any best practice examples that are not too detrimental?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detect the copy paste attempt and display a notification informing the user the website does not allow it, followed up by a sorry.

Otherwise the user will think the browser is faulty.

Comment: Ok. I suspected as much, was hoping there would be something less intrusive. Thanks